# Unable to refresh listview data within same fragments used under different tabs

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have implemented tabs functionality via `SmartTabLayout` library in my android application. At present I have used same `fragment` as viewpager for both of my `tabs`. Since, the only difference is the view is that sorting of listitems. Below is my HomeActivity code:

**HomeActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    final SmartTabLayout viewPagerTab = (SmartTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.viewpagertab);
    viewPagerTab.setCustomTabView(this);

    FragmentPagerItems pages = new FragmentPagerItems(this);
    pages.add(FragmentPagerItem.of("Test1", SampleFragment.class));
    pages.add(FragmentPagerItem.of("Test2", SampleFragment.class));

    FragmentStatePagerItemAdapter adapter = new FragmentStatePagerItemAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager(), pages);

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
    viewPagerTab.setViewPager(viewPager);
}

@Override
public View createTabView(ViewGroup container, int position, PagerAdapter adapter) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(container.getContext());
    View tab = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_tab_icon_and_notification_mark, container, false);
    TextView txtTab=(TextView)tab.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
    switch (position){
        case 0:txtTab.setText("Test1");break;
        case 1:txtTab.setText("Test2");break;
        default:throw new IllegalStateException("Invalid pos - "+ position);
    }
    return tab;
}
```

My SampleFragment.java is as below wherein I do some server request for data and update the `listview` adapter.

**SampleFragment.java**

```
List<Items> lstItems=new ArrayList<>();
static ItemListAdapter mAdapter;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sample, container, false);
    ListView lstviewItems = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lstItems);
    int position = FragmentPagerItem.getPosition(getArguments());
    View emptyView=view.findViewById(R.id.emptyList);
    lstviewItems.setEmptyView(emptyView);
    mAdapter = new ItemsListAdapter(getActivity(),lstItems);
    lstviewItems.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    switch (position){
        case 0:
            //JsonObjectRequest
            loadItems();
            break;
        case 1:
            //sort the loaded items
            break;
    }
    return view;
}

private void loadItems(){
    try {
        JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET,url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        lstItems.clear();
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            //Add item to lstItems
                        }
                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
        });
        testApp.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But even after `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` the `listview` in the current viewPager `tab` i.e. `Test1` tab is not getting refreshed. Whereas when I navigate to `Test2` tab, I can see the changes in the listview, where is data has been loaded properly. Below is the screenshot for 2 different tabs.

[image: Tabs]

I've also searched for this problem and found other solution which did not work for me. One of the solution being, adding a refresh method in `ItemsAdapter` as below:

```
public void refresh(List<Items> items)
{
    this.items = items;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

and instead of `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` I used `mAdapter.refresh(lstItems);`. But unfortunately it did not work either. How can I possibly overcome this. Please let me know if I have to add furthermore details on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is here:

`mAdapter = new ItemsListAdapter(getActivity(),lstItems);`

You create a new instance of ItemsListAdapter and bind it to the listview with

`lstviewItems.setAdapter(mAdapter);`

The problem is that this adapter is `static`. So if you create a new instance you destroy the old adapter and the listview of the other tab has not the adapter anymore that updates your data.

**EDIT:**

I'd recommend to load the data on a central place. Add the response (your data objects) to a manager class. Then implement on every view which using this data a callback (lets say `JsonDataChangedCallback`). Register the classes which implementing the callback to the manager with `Manager.getInstance().registerCallback()`. Then every time your data is changed call `updateCallbacks()` in your manager and all views will be updated. That's the way implemented that process in my app and it works.

**Sample Code:**

```
public class CDMMovieManager {
  private CDMMovieManager() {
    m_Movies = new ArrayList<>();
    m_MovieChangedCallbacks = new ArrayList<>();
  }

  public static synchronized CDMMovieManager getInstance() {
    if(ms_Instance == null)
      ms_Instance = new CDMMovieManager();

    return ms_Instance;
  }

  public void addMovie(CDMMovie p_Movie) {
    m_Movies.add(p_Movie);
    notifyCallbacks();
  }

  /**
   * Registers a movie changed callback
   *
   * @param p_MovieChangedCallback the callback to register
   */
  public void registerMovieChangedCallback(IDMMovieChangedCallback p_MovieChangedCallback) {
    m_MovieChangedCallbacks.add(p_MovieChangedCallback);
  }

  /**
   * Removes a movie changed callback
   *
   * @param p_MovieChangedCallback the callback to remove
   */
  public void removeMovieChangedCallback(IDMMovieChangedCallback p_MovieChangedCallback) {
    m_MovieChangedCallbacks.remove(p_MovieChangedCallback);
  }

  private void notifyCallbacks() {
    for(IDMMovieChangedCallback l_MovieChangedCallback : m_MovieChangedCallbacks) {
      l_MovieChangedCallback.onMoviesChanged();
    }
  }
}
```

And the implementing Class:

```
public class CDMBasicMovieFragment extends Fragment implements IDMMovieChangedCallback {

//...
  @Override
  public void onMoviesChanged() {
    m_Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, that was the quick one. This however solved my issue, but its hitting other way now. I made my `mAdapter` non-static and started getting data in `tab1`, but found nothing in `tab2`. Any thing you can suggest on this?

Comment: That's because of your switch case. You only load data if the current fragment is on position 0. Check my updated post.

Comment: Seems bit confusing. It would be helpful if you add some sample piece of code as demo.. :)

Comment: Sure i'll create another answer. Wait a moment.

Comment: The reason why I made my `mAdapter` as static is that, I declared this in a separate `appController` which extends `Application` and registered this in manifest file. I've also kept my `lstItems` variable in the same `appController` thinking that this would be global usage.

Comment: Thank you so much buddy.. Let me see how I can implement this in my application. Thanks much for your time and efforts once again.. :)