# Refreshing fragment on click of activity's actionBar item

Tags: android, android-fragments

Need to refresh fragment on click of Add Category icon present in the activity's toolbar.

I have an Activty (ProductsAndServicesTab extends AppCompactActivity)
In this activity I have a button on toolbar for Adding category

In this activity I have defined two tabs (Products extends Fragment and Services extends Fragment)

public class ProductsAndServicesTab extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager mViewPager;
private Toolbar mToolbar;
ProgressDialog pb;


TextView show_prof_menu_title_text;
ImageView show_prof_edit_profile_icon, show_prof_logo_menu_icon;

String businessId = null;
String sessionId = null;

static DbOperations dbOperations;
static Context context;



ConnectAndGetResponseInBackground connectAndGetResponseInBackground;

static {
    try {

        context = abcApp.getContext();
        dbOperations = new DbOperations(context);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_products_services_details);

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.inc_tb_top);
    show_prof_menu_title_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.show_prof_menu_title_text);
    show_prof_edit_profile_icon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.show_prof_edit_profile_icon);
    show_prof_edit_profile_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.category);

    show_prof_logo_menu_icon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.show_prof_logo_menu_icon);


    businessId = getIntent().getExtras().getString("businessid");
    sessionId = getIntent().getExtras().getString("sessionid");

    dbOperations.open();


    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

    show_prof_menu_title_text.setText("Items");

    final Drawable upArrow = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_material, null);
    upArrow.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context, android.R.color.white), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    setupViewPager(mViewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.stl_tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));

    changeTabsFont();

    show_prof_edit_profile_icon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            addCategoryDiag();
        }
    });


}


private void changeTabsFont() {

    ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) tabLayout.getChildAt(0);
    int tabsCount = vg.getChildCount();
    for (int j = 0; j < tabsCount; j++) {
        ViewGroup vgTab = (ViewGroup) vg.getChildAt(j);
        int tabChildsCount = vgTab.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < tabChildsCount; i++) {
            View tabViewChild = vgTab.getChildAt(i);
            if (tabViewChild instanceof TextView) {
                Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/pts75f-webfont.ttf");
                ((TextView) tabViewChild).setTypeface(tf);
            }
        }
    }
}


private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {

    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("sessionId", sessionId);
    b.putString("businessId", businessId);

    Products products = new Products();
    products.setArguments(b);


    Services services = new Services();
    services.setArguments(b);


    adapter.addFragment(products, "Products");
    adapter.addFragment(services, "Services");


    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

/*    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return false;
    }*/

    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        onBackPressed();
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


private void addCategoryDiag() {

    android.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(ProductsAndServicesTab.this);
    final android.app.AlertDialog alertDialogMain = builder.create();

    final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View alertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog_add_category, null);

    Button custom_cancel = (Button) alertView.findViewById(R.id.custom_cancel);
    Button custom_ok = (Button) alertView.findViewById(R.id.custom_ok);
    final ListView lv_add_category = (ListView) alertView.findViewById(R.id.lv_add_category);
    final EditText et_add_category = (EditText) alertView.findViewById(R.id.et_add_category);

    final RadioGroup rg_products_services = (RadioGroup) alertView.findViewById(R.id.rg_products_services);


    ArrayList<String> categoryTypes = new ArrayList<String>();
    categoryTypes = dbOperations.getAllCategoryNameForBusinessAndType(businessId, "Products");

  /*  if (categoryTypes == null ||  categoryTypes.size() == 0){
        categoryTypes.add("General");
    }*/

    if (categoryTypes != null && categoryTypes.size() > 0) {
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ProductsAndServicesTab.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, categoryTypes);

        lv_add_category.setAdapter(adapter);
    } else {
        lv_add_category.setAdapter(null);
    }

    custom_cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            alertDialogMain.dismiss();
        }
    });


    rg_products_services.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
            RadioButton getRb_editProf_gender = (RadioButton) radioGroup.findViewById(i);
            getRb_editProf_gender.setChecked(true);
            String type = getRb_editProf_gender.getText().toString();

            et_add_category.setText(null);
            ArrayList<String> categoryTypes = new ArrayList<String>();
            categoryTypes = dbOperations.getAllCategoryNameForBusinessAndType(businessId, type);


            if (categoryTypes != null && categoryTypes.size() > 0) {

                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ProductsAndServicesTab.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, categoryTypes);

                lv_add_category.setAdapter(adapter);
            } else {
                lv_add_category.setAdapter(null);
            }

        }
    });

    custom_ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (!et_add_category.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {

                final String categoryText = et_add_category.getText().toString();
                String categoryTypeStr = null;
                if (rg_products_services.getCheckedRadioButtonId() != -1) {
                    RadioButton getRb_editProf_gender = (RadioButton) rg_products_services.findViewById(rg_products_services.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
                    categoryTypeStr = getRb_editProf_gender.getText().toString();
                }

                boolean doesCategoryExists = dbOperations.checkCategoryExists(businessId, categoryText, categoryTypeStr);

                if (!doesCategoryExists) {


                    if (Utility.isNetworkConnected(ProductsAndServicesTab.this)) {


                        //     Toast.makeText(ProductsAndServicesTab.this, "I m clicked " + categoryTypeStr + " * " + categoryText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        int category_type = -1;
                        if (categoryTypeStr != null && categoryTypeStr.equals("Products"))
                            category_type = 0;
                        if (categoryTypeStr != null && categoryTypeStr.equals("Services"))
                            category_type = 1;

                        pb = new ProgressDialog(ProductsAndServicesTab.this);
                        pb.setMessage("In Progress....Please Wait");
                        pb.setCancelable(false);
                        pb.show();

                        String addCategoryJsonReqStr = FormJson.formAddingCategoryJsonStr(businessId, sessionId, category_type, categoryText);

                        final String finalCategoryTypeStr = categoryTypeStr;
                        connectAndGetResponseInBackground = new ConnectAndGetResponseInBackground() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponseReceived(String result) {

                                pb.dismiss();
                                System.out.println("AddCategory req :" + result);

                                String addedCategoryResponse = ProcessResponse.processAddedCategoryResponse(businessId, finalCategoryTypeStr, categoryText, result);

                                if (addedCategoryResponse != null) {

                                    if (addedCategoryResponse.equals("Success")) {
                                        Toast.makeText(ProductsAndServicesTab.this, categoryText + " added to " + finalCategoryTypeStr + " category successfully..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        alertDialogMain.dismiss();



                                    } else {
                                        Utility.showDialog("Error", addedCategoryResponse, ProductsAndServicesTab.this);
                                    }

                                } else {
                                    Utility.showDialog("Error", "Unexpected error.Please try again later.", ProductsAndServicesTab.this);
                                }

                            }
                        };

                        connectAndGetResponseInBackground.setJson(addCategoryJsonReqStr);
                        connectAndGetResponseInBackground.execute(URLs.PRODUCTS_SERVICES);

                        System.out.println("AddCategory req :" + URLs.PRODUCTS_SERVICES + addCategoryJsonReqStr);


                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(ProductsAndServicesTab.this, "No Internet Connection, please try again..!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(ProductsAndServicesTab.this, "Category already exists.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(ProductsAndServicesTab.this, "Please enter category.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });


    alertDialogMain.setView(alertView);
    alertDialogMain.show();
    alertDialogMain.setCancelable(false);

}


@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();


}
```

}

Products fragment (Same code for Services Fragments) :

public class Products extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

```
AppPreferences appPreferences;

AppCompatSpinner spinr_products_services;
ListView lv_products_services;
SwipeRefreshLayout swiperefresh_products_services;
FloatingActionButton fab_products_services_add_items;


String businessId = null;
String sessionId = null;

boolean isImageSet = false;

int REQUEST_CAMERA = 0, SELECT_FILE = 1;

Bitmap selectedImageBitmap;

ImageView iv_item;

ArrayList<String> categoryTypes = new ArrayList<String>();

ArrayList<CategoryItems_Table> categoryItemsList;


Menu contextualMenu;

ProgressDialog pb;

ProductsAndServicesAdapter productsAndServicesAdapter;

private static DbOperations dbOperations;
static Context context;

static {
    try {
        context = abcApp.getContext();
        dbOperations = new DbOperations(context);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_products, container, false);

    dbOperations.open();
    appPreferences = new AppPreferences(getActivity());

    swiperefresh_products_services = (SwipeRefreshLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.swiperefresh_products_services);
    lv_products_services = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lv_products_services);
    spinr_products_services = (AppCompatSpinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinr_products_services);
    fab_products_services_add_items = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fab_products_services_add_items);


    businessId = getArguments().getString("businessId");
    sessionId = getArguments().getString("sessionId");

    fab_products_services_add_items.setOnClickListener(this);


    getAndSetData(null);



    swiperefresh_products_services.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            getAndSetData(spinr_products_services.getSelectedItem().toString());
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}




public void getAndSetData(String currentCategoryName) {


    categoryTypes = dbOperations.getAllCategoryNameForBusinessAndType(businessId, "Products");
    if (categoryTypes != null && categoryTypes.size() > 0) {
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categoryTypes);

        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        spinr_products_services.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

        if (currentCategoryName != null) {
            int position = ((ArrayAdapter) spinr_products_services.getAdapter()).getPosition(currentCategoryName);
            spinr_products_services.setSelection(position);
        }
    }


    spinr_products_services.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            String categoryName = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
            System.out.println("Products spinnerSelectCategory: " + categoryName);
            categoryItemsList = dbOperations.getAllItemsForTypeBusinessAndCategoryName(businessId, categoryName, "Products");

            if (categoryItemsList != null && categoryItemsList.size() > 0) {
                productsAndServicesAdapter = new ProductsAndServicesAdapter(getActivity(), categoryItemsList, "general", sessionId);
                lv_products_services.setAdapter(productsAndServicesAdapter);
            } else {
                lv_products_services.setAdapter(null);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });

    if (swiperefresh_products_services.isRefreshing()) {
        swiperefresh_products_services.setRefreshing(false);
    }
}
```

Once I press a toolbar button for adding category and after I add a category that newly added category is not displayed in fragment's spinner element.[Activity's toolbar name is items and right side is add category imageButton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xDOa.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend an interface for this. Create a manager class (singleton) and every view which uses the categories have to implement the interface. Then register the implemented views on the manager. You have to add the categories via `manager.getInstance().add(mycategory);`. Inside the add you call `notifyCallbacks();`

I already implemented this logic in my app.
Check my code on this link:

[Unable to refresh listview data within same fragments used under different tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41449017/unable-to-refresh-listview-data-within-same-fragments-used-under-different-tabs/41449211)

Answer (score 0):

To update the fragment you need to use callback to send data from the activity to the fragment. Then update the data received in the fragment. Share the the code for activity and fragment, i'll provide complete solution.

Comment: I have update my code in the question above please check