# Add dynamic item to listview

Tags: android, listview

I need to add items dynamically to listview.

Now i am using FAB (crearEntrenamintoActivity) to open a New activity (crearEjercicioActivity) and here complete the necesary data of the New item to add into listview.

But by this way i need to pass the parceableExtra all time between both activities.

Are there other simpler way to do this?

Edit:

Here when i press FAB button i send to the new activity the extra "entrenamiento" because i need to save all the items of the listview into this object.

```
public void initFAB() {
        FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fabCrearEntrenamiento);
        if (floatingActionButton != null) {
            floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //lanzamos la actividad de crear ejercicio
                    entrenamiento.setUbicacion(etUbicacion.getText().toString());
                    entrenamiento.setHoraInicio(etHoraInicio.getText().toString());
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CrearEjercicioActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("entrenamiento", entrenamiento);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Then in "crearEjercicioActivity" i have this. Here when i press save button i add in the arrayList the new item.

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_save:
                Entrenamiento entrenamiento = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("entrenamiento");
                Ejercicio ejercicio = new Ejercicio();
                EditText titulo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTituloEjercicio);
                ejercicio.setTitulo(titulo.getText().toString());
                entrenamiento.getEjercicios().add(ejercicio);
                Intent intentEjercicio = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CrearEntrenamientoActivity.class);
                intentEjercicio.putExtra("entrenamiento", entrenamiento);
                startActivity(intentEjercicio);
                return true;
            case R.id.action_home:
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DashBoardActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

And finally i do this:

```
if (entrenamiento.getEjercicios().size() > 0) {
            ListView listViewEjercicios = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewEjercicios);
            ArrayList<String> titulosEjercicios = new ArrayList<>();

            for (Ejercicio ejercicio : entrenamiento.getEjercicios()) {
                titulosEjercicios.add(ejercicio.getTitulo());
            }

            ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.simple_row_ejercicio_layout, titulosEjercicios);
            if (listViewEjercicios != null) {
                listViewEjercicios.setAdapter(listAdapter);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more or put code?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend a manager class for this which is singleton. The manager should include data structure like a list or a map. There you can save your objects. If you want to add a new object call `manager.add(yourobject)`. Additionally you can a something like a notify callback. Every view which use the data of the manager have to implement your callback. Register the views on the manager with `manager.registerCallback()`. And everytime when you modify the data of the manager like `add()` or `remove()` you have to call `notifyCallbacks()`.

If you implement my solution then you don't have to create multiple adapter objects. You're working with one list/map object which is saved in your manager. And after modifying the data you just have to call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Check my code example on this post:
[Unable to refresh listview data within same fragments used under different tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41449017/unable-to-refresh-listview-data-within-same-fragments-used-under-different-tabs/41449211#41449211)

Comment: i dont understand very well. Can you explain me a litlle more? I have two activities, the first contains listview and starts the second activity, In the second activity i save a new item that will be included in the listview of the first activity.

Comment: Currently you pass the data of the listview with `parceableExtra` to the second activity. Now in your second activity you have a copy of this passed item. You set a new item to the copy. Finally you set a new adapter. With my solution you don't work with copies. You have a manager which stores the objects. There are no copies anymore. You won't have to call `setAdapter()` multiple times. You'll always work with the same list. At the end you only have to call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` instead of creating a new adapter.

Comment: yes. but i dont understand the relationship between the adapter and the manager. in the second activity i call addMovie(movie) which call     notifyCallbacks(); where loop m_MovieChangedCallbacks calling onMoviesChanged() in CDMBasicMovieFragment, but what is this?
CDMBasicMovieFragment should be my first activity?

And what is the difference between m_Movies  and m_MovieChangedCallbacks ?

Sorry for my doubts

Comment: No problem ;) The manager stores the data which is `m_Movies`. Additionally it stores all callbacks which the manager has to notify when the data is changed (`m_MovieChangedCallbacks`). `CDMBasicMovieFragment` is the class which implements the callback. In your case your activity have to implement the callback. And the callback itself includes just one function named `onMoviesChanged()`. Don't forget to register the callback to the manager. Call `manager.registerCallback(this)`. The example code is for movies. Just rename the functions and variables.

Comment: so... In my first activity i do this:
EjercicioManager.getInstance().registerMovieChangedCallback(this);
        listAdapter  = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.simple_row_ejercicio_layout, EjercicioManager.getInstance().getEjercicios());

                 getEjercicios() return the array like m_Movies.

is this correct?

Comment: thanks. i do this and all its correct. thanks for your help. this is cleaner than i had.

Comment: the last question. when i save the new exercise in the second activity i finish() it and return to the first activity. Should i implement onResume method because i have all in the onCreate method like this:

listViewEjercicios = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewEjercicios);
        EjercicioManager.getInstance().registerMovieChangedCallback(this);
        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.simple_row_ejercicio_layout, EjercicioManager.getInstance().getEjercicios());
        listViewEjercicios.setAdapter(listAdapter);

Comment: You don't have to implement `onResume()`. But you have to implement `onDestroy()` because you also have to call `manager.removeCallback()` to remove the old callback otherwise you'll have a memory leak. And remember if you have another view which uses these objects, just implement the callback and register it to the manager. The data will be refreshed automatically ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could use just one Activity and then have Fragments for each of your two views. The Activity can then hold the reference to your element and handle the communication between the two Fragments by calling public methods on them ([like described here at the bottom](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)).

If you want to stick to activities the intents are probably the recommended approach.

Comment: But i need that the listfragment start New activity and then update the listfragment with the New item. How can i communicate both?