# Best practice for refreshing a ListView with Detail Activities

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

### Question/Discussion

What is in your opinion the best solution (now, 2017) for the following scenario.

> You have a list, the cells contain some data:
>   - A name
>   - A star to indicate if the item is in starred items or not
>   - A status
>
> When you click this list item, you go to a detail page, where it is
>   possible to add the item to your starred items and some other stuff
>   that change the status.
>
> When you go back, the list should get updated so it shows the new info
>   in the list.

This is a very common case in Android apps.

### How I solve this today

- Use a ListView
- List data is set in onResume function

This is by far not the best solution.
So how do you guys handle this in your apps, do you use ListViews, RecyclerView,... where do you trigger the list update,...

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is in your `onResume()` for the first activity, you need to modify the data list that is attached to the ListView Adapter, and then call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mListOfData.clear();
    mListOfData.addAll(fetchLatestData());
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Here, mListOfData is the data list that you passed to your Adapter, and the `fetchLatestData()` method should fetch the latest data from whatever source you have.

Comment: I think this is actually his current solution.

Comment: Yes this is my current solution in one of my projects, but I don't think this is the best (practice) solution.

Answer (score 0):

When you start the details activity , use startactivityforesult. You know how it works , right ? Also keep the clicked list position in an int field. If that item is added to favs in detail page , set result to result_ok. When you navigate back to list activity , in onactivityresult method check if result is ok. If so , modify that row of list data ( remember we saved clicked position in an int field ) and notify adapter about the change

Answer (score 0):

In my app I use a manager which handles the data. All views which want to use the data, implements an interface have to be registered by the manager. If you want to add/modify/delete data you have to implement some methods in the manager class. At the end of each method you have to notify all registered views that data has been changed.

Example code on this link: [Unable to refresh listview data within same fragments used under different tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41449017/unable-to-refresh-listview-data-within-same-fragments-used-under-different-tabs/41449211#41449211)