# Multiple callbacks for one AsynckTask

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I'm Writing an application in which i have different fragment in a ViewPager. In each fragment I use several AsyncTask for fetching data from web server. Some of the fragments needs to call the same AsynTask(service), but if one of them has already called it, as the service takes a while to response, I want to prevent call it againg, instead I want to make the AsyncTask send the result to all fragments who called it. I also need to update de data in all fragments when the user updates a fragment (SwipeToRefresh i.e.). The aproach I have today is a function where I validate if the service has been called, if is not the case, saves a flag to indicate that the service was called, and call the service using an AsyncTask that recieves a Callback interface to send the result to the requesting Fragmnet, if on the other way, the service has already been called, add the Callback to a Callback list which later is traversed in AsyncTask.onPostExecute to send the resull to all fragmnets.

The biggest problem is that when I make several request, as when the user opens the app after some time, leads to memory leaks (GC works too much and app freezes) and the app is terminated. It also doesn't solve the problem to update all fragments in a single call.

This is the code of the procedure I mentioned before (just an example):

```
public class Test {

private static List<Integer> calledServices = new ArrayList<>();
private static Map<Integer, List<Callback>> callbacksMap = new HashMap<>();

public static void call(int serviceId, Callback callback) {
    if (!hasBeenCalled(serviceId)) {
        calledServices.add(serviceId); //saves flag
        ServiceAsyncTask task = new ServiceAsyncTask(serviceId, callback);
        task.execute();
    } else {
        callback.onPreExecute();
        if (callbacksMap.containsKey(serviceId)) {
            callbacksMap.get(serviceId).add(callback);
        } else {
            List<Callback> callbacks = new ArrayList<>();
            callbacks.add(callback);
            callbacksMap.put(serviceId, callbacks);
        }
    }
}

private static boolean hasBeenCalled(int serviceId) {
    return calledServices.contains(serviceId);
}

interface Callback {
    void onPreExecute();

    void onPostExecute(Object object);
}

static class ServiceAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> {
    private final int serviceId;
    private final Callback mCallback;

    ServiceAsyncTask(int serviceId, Callback callback) {
        this.serviceId = serviceId;
        this.mCallback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mCallback.onPreExecute();
    }

    Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
        return WebService.call(serviceId);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
        mCallback.onPostExecute(o);

         if (!callbacksMap.containsKey(serviceId)) return;

        for (Callback callback : callbacksMap.get(serviceId)) {
            callback.onPostExecute(o);
        }

        callbacksMap.remove(serviceId);
        calledServices.remove(serviceId);
    }
}
```

}

I hope you can help me and I apologize for any typos or grammatical error I may have done.

Answer (score 0):

Make your API calling when current fragment is visible.

For example,

```
  private boolean hasLoadedOnce= false; 
  @Override
  public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isFragmentVisible) {
     super.setUserVisibleHint(true);
     if (this.isVisible()) {
         // we check that the fragment is becoming visible
        if (isFragmentVisible && !hasLoadedOnce) {
            new ServiceAsyncTask().execute();
            hasLoadedOnce = true;
        }
     }
  }
```

I hope, this way you can mangage api call inside fragement and update easily.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem like you. I also have a callback which is implemented by every view/fragment which want to use the data. Then I have an asynctask which loads the data. When I get the response I save the object into a manager class which includes the list of callbacks that I have to notify for a view update. So all views/fragments which implements the callback have to be registered on the manager by themselves.

Code Example:
[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41449017/unable-to-refresh-listview-data-within-same-fragments-used-under-different-tabs/41449211#41449211)

Answer (score 0):

You could use enums in java (1.5 or above) like this:-

```
enum Tasks {
   task1, task2
}
```

and pass a parameter of type 'Tasks' in your interface methods like this :-

```
interface Callback {
  void onPreExecute(Tasks task);

  void onPostExecute(Tasks task, Object object);
}
```

and use it like this:-

```
callback.onPreExecute(Tasks.task1); or callback.onPostExecute(Tasks.task1, object);
```